# Why are coordinate maps diffeomorphisms? (A seeming counterexample?)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-functions

In Tu's "An Introduction to Manifolds", Prop 6.10 says:

> If $(U,\phi)$ is a chart on the manifold $M$ of dimension $n$, then the coordinate map $\phi:U\to\phi(U)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a diffeomorphism.

However, I come up with a seeming counterexample from exercise 6.1.

Consider $(\mathbb{R},\psi)$ where $\psi = x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is a homeomorphism but not a diffeomorphism. I don't see why this didn't hold water. Definitely something is wrong... Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a difference between a topological manifold and a differentiable manifold.

Comment: $\phi(U)$ need not be a submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @JohnDouma He’s using this chart to define a differentiable structure on $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two different copies of $\Bbb{R}$ and they’re playing different roles, but you’re not distinguishing them. The first, lets call it $M$ to emphasize it is the ‘abstract manifold’ has a global chart $\psi:M\to\Bbb{R}$ (this $\Bbb{R}$ on the target is our ‘usual’ $\Bbb{R}$). How do we check the smoothness of the map $\psi$? By definition it means we fix an atlas for $M$ and check that for all charts in this atlas, $\psi$ composed with the inverse chart maps give something smooth in the usual multivariable calculus sense.

In our case, $M$ is by definition equipped with the maximal atlas containing the chart $(M,\psi)$. Thus, to check that $\psi$ is smooth, we have to merely check that $\psi\circ\psi^{-1}:\psi[M]\to\Bbb{R}$ is a smooth map. But this is obviously just the identity map of $\Bbb{R}$, $\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}}:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, so it is smooth in the usual calculus sense.

---

To repeat: you’re not taking into account that on the domain of $\psi$, that copy of $\Bbb{R}$ is given a smooth structure *defined* using $\psi$ itself.

Comment: Thanks! I know where I made the mistake!!

Comment: Along these lines, you should check that if $M$ is an arbitrary set, and $(N,\mathcal{A})$ is a smooth manifold with a given maximal atlas, and if you have a bijection $f:M\to N$, then you can always endow $M$ with a maximal atlas (namely for each $(U,\phi)\in\mathcal{A}$, consider $(f^{-1}(U), \phi\circ f|_{f^{-1}(U)})$) such that $f$ becomes a diffeomorphism of $M$ onto $N$. This is the phenomenon of *transport of structure*. The above example is when $(N,\mathcal{A})$ is $\Bbb{R}$ with the usual atlas (i.e containing the identity chart), and $M=\Bbb{R}$ and $f=\psi$.

Comment: This was counterintuitive to me as well when I first learned manifolds. For example, we can use it to make something like a cube into a smooth manifold, by taking the transport map to be a homeomorphism to a sphere (which in turn we need to see is smooth). Cubes do not appear to be smooth, but with this particular setup, it is, because the homeomorphism makes the singular points invisible.